# Mongodb update nested array by id

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document and want to update `state`

Document ID: ObjectId("5a4e5a448b70d50e34d204a5")

Target ID: ObjectId("5a4e5a438b70d50e34d203ea")

I have no idea how to update the state to e.g. 4

```
  {
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a4e5a448b70d50e34d204a5"),
  "name" : "Wirtschaftsdienst",
  "date" : ISODate("2012-10-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
  "comment" : null,
  "tasks" : [ 
      {
          "name" : "Speisen und Getränke",
          "sections" : [ 
              {
                  "start" : 46800,
                  "end" : 72000,
                  "entirely" : true,
                  "assistants" : [ 
                      {
                          "assistant" : {
                              "_id" : ObjectId("5a4e5a438b70d50e34d203ea")
                          },
                          "state" : 3
                      }, 
                      {
                          "assistant" : {
                              "_id" : ObjectId("5a4e5a438b70d50e34d203f4")
                          },
                          "state" : 3
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positional operator [`$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) along with [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/) to get your job done!

Try this query:

```
db.collection.update(
 {"_id" : ObjectId("5a4e5a448b70d50e34d204a5")},
 {$set: {"tasks.$[].sections.$[].assistants.$[element].state":4}},
 {arrayFilters: [ {"element.assistant":{"_id" : 
  ObjectId("5a4e5a438b70d50e34d203ea")} } 
  ], multi:true}
)
```

And the output is:

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a4e5a448b70d50e34d204a5"),
"name" : "Wirtschaftsdienst",
"date" : ISODate("2012-10-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
"comment" : null,
"tasks" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Speisen und Getränke",
        "sections" : [ 
            {
                "start" : 46800,
                "end" : 72000,
                "entirely" : true,
                "assistants" : [ 
                    {
                        "assistant" : {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5a4e5a438b70d50e34d203ea")
                        },
                        "state" : 4.0
                    }, 
                    {
                        "assistant" : {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5a4e5a438b70d50e34d203f4")
                        },
                        "state" : 3.0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That looks promising but I get the error cannot use the part (tasks of tasks.$[].sections.$[].assistants.$[element].state) to traverse the element ({tasks: [ { name: "Speisen und Getränke", sections: [ { start: 46800, end: 72000, entirely: true, assistants: [ { assistant: { _id: ObjectId('5a4e5a438b70d50e34d203ea') }, state: 3 }, { assistant: { _id: ObjectId('5a4e5a438b70d50e34d203f4') }, state: 3 } ] } ] } ]})

Comment: Are u executing the query from robomongo? U need to execite it from mongo shell and preferrably mongo 3. 6.  Even I was getting error when I tried from third party tool such as robo,  once  I tried same query in mongo shell,  it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had mongodb 3.6 already but my nodejs mongoclient was prior 3.x and did not support `arrayFilters`. Now everything is working great ;-)